# PHP Class of composer package not found

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, composer-php, carbon-fields

I am writing a Wordpress plugin to create custom Gutenberg blocks. I am using a composer package called Carbon Fields. But when I try to use the package I am getting an Error:

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Carbon_Fields\Block' not found in /my-path/my-plugin/my-plugin.php on line 10**.

The strange thing is that I can use the Container and Field classes without problems.

**Note**

I have just included the basic file structure and code so that you can focus on the important things.

**File structure**

- my-plugin

  - vendor

    - htmlburger

      - core

        - Block.php
        - Carbon_Fields.php
        - Container.php
        - Field.php
  - my-plugin.php

**Code**

*my-plugin.php*

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'carbon_fields_init' );
function carbon_fields_init() {
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'vendor/autoload.php';
        \Carbon_Fields\Carbon_Fields::boot();
}

use \Carbon_Fields\Block;
use \Carbon_Fields\Filed;

Block::make( __( 'Hero Image' ) )
    ->add_fields( array(
        Field::make( 'text', 'heading', __( 'Block Heading' ) ),
    ) )
    ->set_render_callback( function ( $fields, $attributes, $inner_blocks ) {
        ?>

        <div class="block">
            <div class="block__heading">
                <h1><?php echo esc_html( $fields['heading'] ); ?></h1>
            </div><!-- /.block__heading -->

        <?php
    } );
```

*Block.php*

```
namespace Carbon_Fields;

class Block extends Container {
    public static function make() {
        return call_user_func_array( array( 'parent', 'make' ), array_merge( array( 'block' ), func_get_args() ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer from a portuguese tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKY-7_wR2n0). I had to wrap the block creation in a function and set that function as a callback for the carbon_fields_register_fields action hook.

```
use Carbon_Fields\Field;
use Carbon_Fields\Block;

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'crb_load' );
function crb_load() {
    require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );
    \Carbon_Fields\Carbon_Fields::boot();
}

add_action( 'carbon_fields_register_fields', 'crb_add_test_block' );
function crb_add_test_block() {
    Block::make( __( 'My Shiny Gutenberg Block' ) )
        ->add_fields( array(
            Field::make( 'text', 'heading', __( 'Block Heading' ) ),
            Field::make( 'rich_text', 'content', __( 'Block Content' ) ),
        ) )
        ->set_render_callback( function ( $fields, $attributes, $inner_blocks ) {
            ?>

            <div class="block">
                <div class="block__heading">
                    <h1><?php echo esc_html( $fields['heading'] ); ?></h1>
                </div><!-- /.block__heading -->

                <div class="block__content">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $fields['content'] ); ?>
                    <a href="">Reload</a>
                </div><!-- /.block__content -->
            </div><!-- /.block -->

            <?php
        } );
}
```